# ListBox Selection Breaks Inside ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf

Using the XAML below the selection behavior of my ListBox is broken. If I try to select the right-most item the scroll jumps to the left and the wrong ListBoxItem gets selected:

```
 <Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 6</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 7</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 8</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 9</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 10</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 11</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 12</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 13</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 14</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 15</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 16</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 17</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 18</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 19</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item 20</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The issue is not present if I remove the ScrollViewer and use the ListBox's ScrollViewer instead. The reason I am doing this is because in my actual application I use a derived ScrollViewer control that allows for scrolling during a drag/drop operation. Any suggestions or alternative approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be wrapping the `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer`. Instead, edit its template directly.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsPresenter Margin="8,8,8,0"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 6</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 7</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 8</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 9</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 10</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 11</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 12</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 13</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 14</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 15</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 16</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 17</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 18</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 19</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 20</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks this resolved the issue. In my actual application I have more than just the ListBox and need to scroll them all together. In this case I was able to use a ControlTemplate like your example but exclude the internal ScrollView and then keep the wrapping ScrollView. Both approaches resolved the strange selection behavior.